# Is there a better way to programatically access tables using SQL

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

Using MS SQL2000 at present if that makes any difference.

Is there a better way than the method below to be able to programatically access a table ?

```
declare @tableName as varchar(50)
declare @sql varchar(4000)

set @tableName = 'User'

print @tableName

If EXISTS(
select TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_name = ''+@TableName+''
)
BEGIN
    set @sql = 'select * from [' + @tableName + ']'
    exec(@sql)

end
```

Essentially Im trying to create a simple Mapping tool for CRUD operations so that I need only one Sproc for each operation, and I can pass in my parameterised object, a table name and let the database do the rest.  This is purely for my own personal education, hence why Im not using an established framework, so if there are any major gotcha's with my idea or the code above, I'd appreciate knowing as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is complete example to create a SP by follow your initial code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CustomSelect (@tableName as varchar(50))
AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @sql varchar(4000)

If EXISTS(
select TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_name = @tableName
)
BEGIN
    set @sql = 'select 1 as Found, * from [' + @tableName + ']'
    exec(@sql)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    select 0 as Found
END
```

This SP **always return a recordset** so you can check `the value of the field FOUND` to know if the table exist or not

**usage:**

```
EXEC CustomSelect 'User'
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Though it doesn help me in the situation where I need to insert a record. I guess I cant have a generic one size fits all sproc there as different objects would have differing numbers of parameters. Back to the drawing board for that one I guess!

Comment: This SP is only for select records from a Table that you can pass as a parameter. To insert record sure you need to create a specific SP for each situation and this is a normal way to do.